# client-side templating

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, client-side-templating

Its been a while since i am working with the AJAX and getting templates from server-side hence creating huge traffic.

Fetching same HTML on single page with only different data, sometimes i feel guilty that i can do better than that.

Then an idea clicked in my mind and i researched on client-side templating.

Only thing i found good enough (i thought so since i did not practiced it yet), was jQote2 http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote2/.

I just want suggestion from gurus that is it worth? 
Is there another good alternative?

Comment: You could also have a look at [link]https://github.com/janl/mustache.js[/link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my favorite:

http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

It looks like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="user_tmpl">
  <% for ( var i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ) { %>
    <li><a href="<%=users[i].url%>"><%=users[i].name%></a></li>
  <% } %>
</script>
```

Its author is John Resig, creator of jQuery.
Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Hi @Edgar, actually jQoute is extended by aefxx from the same code of Javascript Micro Templating by John Resig.

Comment: Accepted your answer, because it was closest to what i initially started and selected as final solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used jQote but I have used jQuery Templates which I believe is the official templating solution although someone might correct me on that.  I've only had the chance to use it in a few home projects but so far I really like it especially for rendering out static content like in my news ticker example.

You can take a look at it here [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)

Dave Ward has some 
[nice blog posts](http://encosia.com/2010/10/05/using-external-templates-with-jquery-templates/)  and also [Stephen Walther](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2011/03/29/jquery-templates-talk-slides-and-code.aspx)

I've done a few [jsFiddle's](http://jsfiddle.net/WXgrM/1/) that show some basic syntax

Comment: Hi @Nicky, Thanks for your response but i think jQoute have more control in templates since we can write javascript as it is in it.

Comment: +1, Thanks for your response, i love most of solution provided by the brilliant jQuery team.

Comment: Well thanks for the upvote Imran.  It is good to see there are a few other options out there.  Mustache being one that has caught my eye.